# Типизация не проходит компиляцию

Tags: typescript

```
//Property 'userId' does not exist on type 'ICustomer | IMultiResult<ICustomer>
```

оно же есть в ICustomer не пойму что не так

```
interface IMultiResult<T> {
result: T[];
totalCount: number;
}

interface IResponse<T> {
    body: T | IMultiResult<T>;
    status: keyof typeof EResponseStatus;
    errorCode: keyof typeof EErrorCodes;
}

export type TResponse<T> = Promise<IResponse<T>>;

export interface ICustomer {
    id: string;
    userId: string;
    addressId: string;
}

export class CustomerService {
 static getCustomerById(id: string): TResponse<ICustomer> {
        return fetch(URLS.CUSTOMER.ID(id)).then(res => res.json());
    }
}

const { body: {userId, addressId} } = await CustomerService.getCustomerById(id);
```

Comment: Но его нет в IMultiResult<ICustomer>, а TS не знает какой из этих типов вернётся в ответе.

Comment: @AlexeyTen а наличие | не как на это не влияет?

Comment: Как раз влияет. Вы написали что ваша функция вернёт либо одну курицу либо ящик с курицами. А потом, не проверяя что вернулось, пытаетесь «оторвать у курицы ножку», но если в ответе придёт ящик куриц, то у него нет ножек. Что отрывать? Именно на это и ругается TS

Comment: @AlexeyTen понял значит так не получится

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо

Comment: Нужно сначала проверять что именно вернулось

Comment: @AlexeyTen не особо понял как просто отдельно тип сделаю TResponseMany

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126659/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-armen).